# Getting label to display one decimal space?

Tags: qgis, labeling

The attribute table correctly shows all data for counties. Some labels show one decimal and other labels shows as none.

I have tried to change the decimal places in the Layer Properties (Formatting-Formatting) section to 1, but this does nothing to the labels.

Comment: Do you want to display one decimal space in the attribute table or in labels on the map?

Answer (score 14):

I always use the `format_number` function via the expression editor (it's under Strings).

For example this expression sets all the values to have 2 decimal places:

```
 format_number( P_MALE,2)
```