# QGIS expression, format number to number of decimals

Tags: qgis-expression

I am using QGIS to plan a cable layout. Knowing the resitance per metre in the cables, lenght of cables and the current draw of each site, I can calculate the voltage available at each site.

[image]

The formula I am using to calculate the voltage gives a lot of decimals, so I round it to one decimal.

```
 concat(round(voltageformula(),1),'V')
```

In some cases, this just gives me an integer (see the point in the upper left). Are there some other rounding or formatting function that would always return a number with one digit after the decimal point?

Comment: Looks like it's answered here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257057/getting-label-to-display-one-decimal-space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in that link, the answer would be:

`concat(format_number(voltageformula(),1),'V')`

That will truncate so if you need to round it would be:

`concat(format_number(round(voltageformula(),1),1),'V')`

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, format_number() was definately rounding now (v3.34) - I tried to do format_number(voltageformula()+0.05,1) and the numbers became too high. If I just did format_number(voltageformula(),1), I got the right number. (The '43' that got me started on this, turned out to be 42.97 with two decimal places, and I got 43.0 with just the format_number()